# How to view the disk use of a directory ignoring hard links in macOS

Tags: macos, du

Using

```
du -d 0
```

you can see the disk usage of the directory you're currently in. Hard links are counted as well.

I'm looking for the command that does this, but does not count the size of the hard links. On Ubuntu this can be done with `du id -0`. Is there an equivalent for macOS?